# Method always returns void in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

I use WCF for creating a service. The service implements a method that returns bool type:

```
    public interface IUserService 
    {
        [OperationContract(Name="LogIn")]
        bool LogIn(string login, string password);
    }
```

Than in my Windows Phone 8.1 SL application I want to call this method so I do it like this:

```
userService.UserServiceClient userService;
userService = new UserService.UserServiceClient();
userService.LogInCompleted += UserService_LogInCompleted;

userService.LogInAsync(login, password);
```

`LogInComplited` event I want to get this bool value which this method should return, but **there is not `e.Result` property available** :

```
private void UserService_LogInCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     bool exists = e.Result;  // Result doesn't exists, dunno why
}
```

Please someone explain me why the is not `e.Result` available in this event? And how to get bool value which `LogIn` method returns?

Comment: uzytkownikUsluga_ZalogujUzytkownikaCompleted && userService_LogInCompleted

Comment: Sorry, I had polish names and I translated them to english for this question. Forgot to edit this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
userService.UserServiceClient userService = new UserService.UserService Client();
userService.LogInCompleted += (a, ae) =>
 {
    if (ae.Result != null)
    {
       bool exists = ae.Result;
    }
  };
userService.LogInAsync(login, password);
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks a lot. But I see this code structure for the first time. What is the difference between this and automatically created event like in my question?

Comment: Your event args are wrong! you need to pass the args related to the service,  something like this userService.LogInCompleted  += new EventHandler<userService.LogInCompletedCompletedEventArgs>(UserService_LogInCompleted);

Comment: then I type `userService.LogInCompleted +=` and then I start typing `new Event` and press TAB it fills it with `EventHandler<SystemComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>`. I see that I don't have `LogInCompletedEventArgs` in my WCF service client. Why?

Comment: I guess my structure would be easy for you, create the service client, add the completed event and then invoke the async method. otherwise follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx